# How to distinguish issues to project while retrieving all issues from all projects?

Tags: java, json, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to retrieve all issues for all projects belonging to a JIRA instance.
In the [JIRA 6.3 REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5109) I found this command: `/rest/api/2/search`. As a description it only says "Searches for issues using JQL", nothing more.

When I test it with [Jira's Demo](https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search) I get the latest 50 issues. But where (or, from which projects) are these issues coming from? Are these issues coming from all of Jira's projects, which can be found here https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/BrowseProjects.jspa#all?

Comment: I don't understand a thing here, can you please calrify your problem? Also, add a descriptive title, _Where do the issues come from?_ is far too vague and general.

Comment: i suggest u change the title to sth more descriptive.

Comment: Ok, done! I hope, it's more descriptive now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, It seems that you did not understand the [API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e5109) that you provided on your question or did not pay enough attention to it.

If you see on the `request query parameters` section there will have the `maxResults` parameter which states:

> the maximum number of issues to return **(defaults to 50)**. The maximum allowable value is dictated by the JIRA property **'jira.search.views.default.max'**. If you specify a value that is higher than this number, your search results will be truncated.

The bold part on this text it was what you did not pay attention or saw at all.

So you depends on the value that is configured on your Jira instance. Look at there and use the link as:

> [https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?jql&maxResults=[QUANTITY]](https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?jql&maxResults=%5bQUANTITY%5d)

I think there is no rest function to retrieve all issues from all projects as it could generate a big response, so you will have to paginate your requests using:

> https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?jql&startAt=0&maxResults=1000

Then again

> https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?jql&startAt=1001&maxResults=1000

And so on...

Hope it helps you to understand.

**Edit**

The result is from all projects. If you want to add a specific project then you have to change your `jql` parameter. An example would be: `jql=project="test"` of course that the double quotes and the equal sign would have to be encoded as a get parameter.

Again you didn't saw the specification there is a link to the JQL specification: [JQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching)

Comment: Ok, thank you. But which project do the latest 50 issues come from? Does it come from a specific project or from all available projects?

Comment: `The result is from all projects`: This is everything I wanted to know. Thank you! :)